# VS2012, Window Phone 8 Compilation Issues

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to compile a Windows Phone 8 app on Visual studio 2012 but I keep getting an error stating that I need a 64bit machine running Windows 8 pro... but I have a 64bit machine running Windows 8.

Is there a Windows 8 Pro? There is only an Win8 Pro (Upgrade) and from the MSDN Downloads there are only Win8 and Win8 Enterprise.

**Error Message**

[image: windows phone 8 error message]

**System Info**

[image: System info]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Win8 Pro or Enterprise for Hyper-V roles. Your machine looks to be a Win8 basic edition.

Comment: Why is Microsoft making it so difficult to build windows apps? first you need windows 8, 64 bit which I bought. Now I need but win8  Enteprise! My android apps were built on WinXP x86

Comment: Alas we devs don't rule the world :) Valid feedback @Tawani and will pass it forward when I can. That said I hear that the overall experience has improved.